# JAVA - string array output incorrect

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop

```
    public static String getGradeDst(String inputArray) {
    String str = inputArray;
    String gradeDst = "";
    int count[] = new int[256];
    int len = str.length();
    for (int i=0;i < len; i++)
        count[str.charAt(i)]++;
    char ch[] = new char[str.length()];
    for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
        ch[i] = str.charAt(i);
        int find = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            if (str.charAt(i) == ch[j])
                find++;
        }
        if (find == 1) {
        gradeDst = str.charAt(i) + ": " + count[str.charAt(i)] + "\n";
        }
    }    
    return gradeDst;
    }
```

My problem is that I get the output 
Total grades are :
A: 5

but no B, C, D, E or F, ive been racking my brain for hours but I cant seem to be able to fix the problem, any help would be fantastic.

Comment: what is your input value and  expected output.?

Comment: And could you give an input example with expected output?

Comment: We cannot debug what we don't know it's supposed to do. What are the input and expected output and why?

Comment: have you checked this? if (find == 1) {
        gradeDst = str.charAt(i) + ": " + count[str.charAt(i)] + "\n";
        }
this makes sure only A gets printed. Also: if you remove the if, you would only print the last, since you overwrite the data, instead of appending it

Comment: Hey guys, the input is a string made up of A's B's C's D's E's and F's and the idea is to count the number of times these repeat and use this class's method to call it, store the info then print it. Can I print it from inside this method?

Answer (score 0):

just make this adjacent:

```
if (find == 1) {
   System.out.println(gradeDst);  // i added only this line
   gradeDst = str.charAt(i) + ": " + count[str.charAt(i)] + "\n";       
}
```

**input:**

```
 String str="fweekk";
```

**output:**

```
f:1
w:1
e:2
k:2
```

You were only printing the last character.

To achieve the same result using StringBuilder make following changes at line 3, 17 and 20:

```
StringBuilder gradeDst = new StringBuilder();

gradeDst.append(str.charAt(i) + ": " + count[str.charAt(i)] + "\n");

return gradeDst.toString();
```